# Passing JSON to curl in Groovy seems platform dependent

Tags: curl, gradle, groovy

I've dived into Groovy for functional testing a WebAPI.  I'm finding  List.execute() immensely frustrating to get working on both Windows and Linux.  I can't get the same JSON string to work on both.

Here's what I've had to resort to:

```
private createLeaderboard(String name) {
    def url = 'http://localhost:8888/v1/tournaments'
    // Here's the JSON
    def body = '{"name":"' + name + '"}'
    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        // I have to surround with single quotes to get working on Windows
        body = "'" + body + "'"
    }
    def content = "content-type:application/json"
    def command = ['curl', '-s', '--request', 'POST', '--data', body, '--header', content, url]
    println "command:" + command
    def proc = command.execute()
    proc.waitFor()
    def jsonstr = proc.in.text
    assertEquals(0, proc.exitValue())
    def obj = JSON.parseText(jsonstr)
    return obj
}
```

If I don't surround the JSON body with single quotes on windows, the application sees

```
name:thename
```

with both the braces and the double quotes removed.  But if I surround it with single quotes, Linux sees

```
'{"name":"thename"}'
```

which also breaks the JSON parser in the app.

I should add I'm using gradle with the appengine plugin and running in a appengineFunctionalTest task, if it has any bearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than playing with the shell and trying to work around the horrible nature of command line expression parameters, you could use the [`groovy-wslite` library](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite)

Then your method becomes:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import wslite.rest.*

private createLeaderboard(String name) {
    def client = new RESTClient('http://localhost:8888')
    def response = client.post(path:'/v1/tournaments',
                               accept:'application/json',
                               headers:['Content-Type':'application/json']) {
        text new JsonBuilder([name: name]).toString()
    }
    response.json
}
```